# Regarding SQL Inject me Firefox add-on?

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection

Using SQL Inject Me Firefox add-on,I have selected the check-boxes then click on Execute button of SQL Inject Me tool.

After getting result, it has displayed following responses

```
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1 UNI/**/ON SELECT ALL FROM WHERE
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: ' OR username IS NOT NULL OR username = '
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: %31%27%20%4F%52%20%27%31%27%3D%27%31
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6,name FROM sysObjects WHERE xtype = 'U' --
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1'1
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1 AND ASCII(LOWER(SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 1 name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'), 1, 1))) > 116
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1' AND non_existant_table = '1
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1 AND USER_NAME() = 'dbo'
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1' AND 1=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablenames); --
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: '; DESC users; --
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1'1
Server Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Tested value: 1' OR '1'='1
```

Please find attached image.

I want to know what is exactly 302 moved temporarily?

Is my site is vulnerable?

[image: 302 moved temp]

Comment: Do you need any further help with this question?

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't used SQL Inject Me plugin before, it is hard to tell if you are vulnerable or not by the data and screenshot you shared.

The 302 Moved Temporarily is a HTTP response. It means that the webserver wants to send you to a different page. If this HTTP response was sent to your Firefox it would lead to Firefox loading a different page, such as the index or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

When you get into server redirects as responses to errors you caused with SQL injection strings (302 moved temporarily), you are entering Blind SQL Injection territory.
As the [SQL Inject Me docs](http://labs.securitycompass.com/exploit-me/sql-inject-me/sql-inject-me-faq/) state:

> its ability to detect SQL Injection is limited by the responses received from the server.  Testing for advanced attacks, such as blind SQL injection, may require additional manual testing.

I recommend you move this test to another tool.  I've found that [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/) is very good at blind SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

From the form parameters displayed in the screenshot it looks like it is testing a password change form.

The parameters of interest are: `uname`, `ppwd`, `npwd`, `cpwd`

It appears that the `cpwd` parameter is the one being tested, which I would guess is the parameter for the confirmation of password change?

The `302 Moved Temporarily` is a HTTP response code where the server is redirecting the user. This could be because the `cpwd` does not match the `npwd` value (i.e. new password and confirmation do not match as the tool has replaced `cpwd` with its data to test with).

So this appears to be a false positive (if my assumptions on the tool, page and parameters are correct). I have not used this particular plugin before, but like [@mcgyver5](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/47186/8340) I recommend [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/) so you should also test with this.